# How to list branche that a commit or file change starting on?

Tags: git

How to list branche that a commit or file change starting on?

I have a file that changes in git and I did a

```
gitk <filename>
```

to see the history on it but from the commit I would like to know which branch was it in at the time.. I have the programmer but not the branch it was started in

Comment: You probably want `gitk --all <filename>` ?

Comment: @PaulR Better yet, `gitk --all -- <filename>` to avoid conflicts between `<filename>` and similarly named branches/tags...

Answer (score 1):

Specifically, it sounds like you want to know which branch head was the parent of the commit when it was created. However, commits do not store this information.